# jQuery Clean Up

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, push

I'm fairly new to jQuery and JavaScript in general.

I wrote this code for a simple Push menu but I feel like there is probably a better way to write this since some of it seems to repeat.

Any suggestions would be great.

Full code can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/Digitango/pen/VzyZyO):

```
//Mobile Push menu

// Open or close menu using menu bar icon or clicking outside of the menu
$('.menu-icon').click(function() {
    $('.main-content').toggleClass('push-open push-close');  
    $('.menu-icon').toggleClass('push-open push-close');
});

// Close menu with X icon
$('.close-icon').click(function() {
  $('.main-content').toggleClass('push-open push-close'); 
  $('.menu-icon').toggleClass('push-open push-close');
});

//Close menu on link click
$('.menu a').click(function() {
  $('.main-content').toggleClass('push-open push-close'); 
  $('.menu-icon').toggleClass('push-open push-close');
});

// Close with esc key
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
    if( $('.main-content').hasClass('push-open') ){
      $('.main-content').addClass('push-close');
      $('.main-content').removeClass('push-open');
    }
    if( $('.menu-icon').hasClass('push-open') ){
      $('.menu-icon').removeClass('push-open');         
      $('.menu-icon').removeClass('push-close');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why not just make a general class? That way you only need one `$('.menu_class').click(function() {
  $('.closing_class').toggleClass('push-open push-close'); 
});`

Comment: @JamesJohnston & Heck - you don't need two classes at all. Only one :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ? I commented how he should use a single general class to toggle something. Fixed because all I did was copy his previous code, but I updated it with a better example.

Comment: @JamesJohnston no, your suggestion is OK, I was just saying that having `'push-open push-close'` is odd. You need only one of them (and logically a default styling - which is - thinking *JS-last* - always the opened/visible state. A `.push-close` is all it's needed :) )

Comment: So you have three different click handlers, all running the same function -- why not move it to a named function, and create a single click handler like `$(".menu-icon, .close-icon, .menu a").on("click", function(){...}) By doing this, you aren't duplicating functionality. Take a look at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZyNaR#anon-login

Comment: Requests for code reviews of working code really belong on the code review stack exchange.

Comment: I appreciate all of the help, there are a lot of examples that are very helpful. I am going to need to play around a bit to get a feel for how the new stuff works. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
(function(){

    //Mobile Push menu

    //var $mainContent = $('.main-content');
    //var $menuIcon = $('menu-icon');
    var $toggleContent = $('.main-content, .menu-icon');

    $('.menu-icon, .close-icon, .menu a').on('click', function() {
        toggleOpen(); 
    });

    // Close with esc key
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
      var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode || e.code;
      if (keyCode === 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
          toggleOpen(); 
      }
    });

    function toggleOpen(){
        if($toggleContent.hasClass('push-open') ){
            $toggleContent.removeClass('push-open').addClass('push-close');
        }else{
            $toggleContent.removeClass('push-close').addClass('push-open');
        }
    }

})(); // End mobilePush
```

What I like about module style is that it lets you declare variables outside of the scope of your functions and events, such as `$toggleContent`, which can be used all over inside of that module without cluttering up the global namespace.

With jQuery you can also chain together actions and methods like  `$toggleContent.removeClass('push-open').addClass('push-close');` which definitely helps with readability and eliminating redundant lines of code.

The reason I went with my own 'toggle' function is because you were toggling `'push-open'` and `'push-close'` at the same time. When I watched in the console, it was adding/removing both classes simultaneously. I suspected you wanted to remove one and add the other. Also, with your own function you can add a callback which may come in handy.

Hope that helps

**Updated**

Removed `mobilePush` altogether as it wasn't necessary, and added `.which`.

> "The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode.
>   It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input."

One thing I'm reading though is **KeyboardEvent.which** has been depreciated, and now either `event.key` (to get the character) or `event.code` can be used. It's recommended to do something like:

```
var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode || e.code
```

If you still had to support anything below IE9 - god forbid -, `.keyCode` will work but not `.which`.

Comment: Why exposing `mobilePush` globally? Also your example makes no sense... *`I suspected you wanted to remove one and add the other`* ... That's exactly what your code does :) You're over-engineering that `toggleOpen` function. All you need is `$toggleContent.toggleClass('push-open push-close');` one line instead of 5. https://jsfiddle.net/ejt23dku/

Comment: Also you should use the normalized `jQueryEvent.which` instead of `Event.keyCode`, than `===` instead of `==` etc etc... bringing your code (in the hope it's good) to this: https://jsfiddle.net/goj5beha/ - Hope that helped

Comment: `.toggleClass()` the way you suggested assumes push-close is already present on his HTML elements. `.which()` is a valid point and you're right, he could remove mobilePush as well. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Nope. You can also remove the classes from HTML ad it will still work. I've set the close class in HTML just to make the buttons red initially.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't work quite well, on scroll you're losing both your icons. The menu icon on page scroll, and the close icon on menu scroll.
You're using a general class which can add confusion to your styling.
You're toggling two classes, when instead all you need is a default style and a single "toggled" class.

#### What about no JS at all?

- 0 lines of JS
- A checkbox to toggle states
- `label` elements to toggle our checkbox
- Animate depending on the checkbox's `:checked` state
- Use in CSS the General Sibling Combinator `~` to target all the needed elements like `#over`, `#menu`, `#page`... which are the checkbox's next siblings.

***Here you go***

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;} /* Don't transition on "*" !! */
html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

/* === CLOSED STYLES === (in order of HTML apperance :D ) */

/* CHECKBOX USED AS MENU TOGGLER */
#ckb { display: none; } /* Hide checkbox button */

/* MENU-BUTTON - notice it's placement in HTML */
#bttn {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  transition: left .3s, transform .8s; /* will animate left and rotation */
}

/* OVERLAY - To overlay the page and on click closes the menu */
#over{
  position: fixed;
  z-index:1;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;      /* hidden initially */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .8s; /* we'll transition opacity */
}

/* MENU */
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: -285px;
  width: 285px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .3s;
}
#menu ul {list-style: none; padding: 32px 24px;}
#menu li > * {padding: 5px 10px; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; color:#f0b; }

/* PAGE AND CONTAINER */
#page {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #bbb;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 0; /* needed since we'll transition this prop */
  background: #eee;
  padding: 32px 56px;
  transition: left .3s;
}

/* === OPEN STYLES === (in order of HTML apperance :D ) */

#ckb:checked ~ #bttn {left: 248px; transform: rotate(180deg);}
#ckb:checked ~ #bttn:before {content: "\f00d";} /* the fa-close character */
#ckb:checked ~ #over {visibility: visible; opacity: 1;}
#ckb:checked ~ #menu {left: 0px;}
#ckb:checked ~ #page > .container {left: 285px;}
```

```html
<input id="ckb" type="checkbox">
<label for="ckb" id="bttn" class="fa fa-bars"></label>
<label for="ckb" id="over"></label>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><label for="ckb">CLICK ME :)</label></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Link One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">There's more</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section id="page">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <p style="height:1000px; border:2px dashed gray;">Lorem</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is a very interesting CSS approach I am going to have to examine how this works as well. Thank you so much!